# I have encounter a bug when compiling with zlib on 64-bit Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, zlib

I am trying to build a large system (Alaska Satellite Facility Mapready Tools) on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit from source. The make fails with the error

```
/usr/include/zlib.h:86:5: error: 'z_const' does not name a type
```

This was tagged as a serious bug in <strike>zlib</strike> *sword* two years ago

```
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=707537
```

but seems to be still present. I install from the Ubuntu package manager with

```
apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Installing zlib 1.2.8 did not help. Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: It is rather bug in sword, not in zlib. Maybe the same fix would work for the program you are trying to build

Comment: The fix, as I understand it, is:  "The patch actually is trivial. Just remove the internal zconf.h." But I can find only one zconf.h on my system:  /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/zconf.h

Comment: They mean `zconf.h` in the source of your program (if any). But this may be unrelated as well.

Comment: I see, thanks. There is a zconf.h in the source so I'll remove it and see what happens.

Comment: Seems the build wanted its own zlib.h and zconf.h, but was finding the system zlib.h in /usr/include first. I moved it temporarily to /usr/local/include (where png could still find it) and the whole thing compiled.